# PHP imagecolorallocate not working

Tags: php, gd

I am running a site off of BlueHost, with `PHP 5.4`, and `GD Version bundled (2.0.34 compatible)` - a high enough GD to use [`imagecreatetruecolor()`](http://www.php.net/imagecreatetruecolor)

I am cropping an image, and sometimes the cropped image does not entirely fill the output thumb. `imagecreatetruecolor()` leaves it with a black background wherever the resampled image isn't covering the output thumb, as shown below

[image: Thumb, with black background]

but I would like it to be a WHITE, or TRANSPARENT background.

**PHP:**

```
$tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

$color = imagecolorallocate($tci, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($tci, 0, 0, $color);

imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, $x, $y, $w, $h, $wOr, $hOr);
imagejpeg($tci, $preview, $qual);
```

I am not having an issue with resampling the image, or using `imagecreatetruecolor()`, but for whatever reason, I cannot get the background color to white.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

If I comment out the line

```
imagecopyresampled(...)
```

then it gives the correct background color that I set in `imagecolorallocate` and `image fill`. It's the `imagecopyresampled` that's causing the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672940/php-imagecopyresampled-adds-black-background perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what it is. I'm going to have to play around with those values until something comes out that I like.